# adding shadow to cell causes laggy scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uiview

So I have a UIView which has a shadow:

```
[containerFrame.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
[containerFrame.layer setShadowRadius:4.0];
[containerFrame.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:34/255.f green:25/255.f blue:25/255.f alpha:1.0].CGColor];
[containerFrame.layer setShadowOpacity:0.4];
```

with this in place, my scrolling FPS drops to 20-30. Remove the shadow and then boom, my FPS is back to 60 and scrolling is as smooth as butter. Now the question is I need ti have a shadow effect around this box/container view. How do I achieve this without slowing down scrolling?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try setting the shadow path:

```
[containerFrame.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
[containerFrame.layer setShadowRadius:4.0];
[containerFrame.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:34/255.f green:25/255.f blue:25/255.f alpha:1.0].CGColor];
[containerFrame.layer setShadowOpacity:0.4];

// New line
[containerFrame.layer setShadowPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:containerFrame.bounds].CGPath];
```

> If you have to animate this view (and especially if it’s part of a
>   UITableViewCell) you will probably notice stutters in the animation. 
>   This is because calculating the drop shadow for your view requires
>   Core Animation to do an offscreen rendering pass to determine the
>   exact shape of your view in order to figure out how to render its drop
>   shadow.  (Remember, your view could be any complex shape, possibly
>   even with holes in it.)

From [On the importance of setting shadowPath](http://markpospesel.wordpress.com/2012/04/03/on-the-importance-of-setting-shadowpath/).

Comment: how do I set the radius and stuff with a path?

Comment: I am not seeing my shadow after adding that line

Comment: @aherlambang there was a bug in my paste - use `containerFrame.bounds` instead of `self.bounds` at the end of my inserted line.

Comment: Got it! So which is actually faster using rasterize or using shadowPath?

Comment: nice! just adding the shadowpath and now scrolling works like a charm! thanks

Comment: @MichaelRobinson its wokring . but my app supported in both orienation and UIBezierPath shadow is not working properly when orientation change. Please suggest me to resolved this.

Comment: @Coder you'd get the best results by opening a question on this site!

Comment: orientation changes cause a `UIView` animation, but `shadowPath` is not animatable by the normal `UIView` animation.  To animate `shadowPath` you must use a `CABasicAnimation` on the layer, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5924734/1693173).

Answer (score 1):

Set `containerFrame.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;` The reason it slows down is because calculating the shadow is expensive.  Rasterizing will collapse the view into an image so it will be much quicker.

Comment: I tried rasterizing it.. but it's not as fast as I wanted, it is faster

Comment: Too fast?  Is that seriously what you mean?

Comment: so which one is better, using shadowPath or using rasterize?

Comment: It depends on your situation.  If your view changes a lot, use shadow path, if your view is static use rasterize.  There is no need to keep the views separate for rendering if the view's appearance doesn't change often.